# How to add DISTINCT to a column in select query

Tags: sql-server

Can you help me how to use `DISTINCT` in this query?

```
DECLARE @ReadData NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @ReadData = 'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RM.ReceiverDate) AS [S. No.] 
                    ,DISTINCT RM.ReceiverId 
                    ,RM.ReceiverDateas [Receiver Date]
                    ,VM.VendorName  as [Vendor Name]
                    ,VM.VendorID
            FROM Receiver RM
            LEFT OUTER JOIN VendorMaster VM on VM.VendorID = RM.VendorId
            WHERE  ['+ @ColumnName + '] LIKE 
                CASE WHEN ' + @Filter+ ' = 0  THEN  ''%' + @Value + '%'''+
                        ' WHEN ' + @Filter + ' = 1 THEN '''+ @Value + '%'''+ 
                        ' WHEN ' + @Filter + ' = 2 THEN ''%' + @Value +''' END  
                AND VM.IsActive = 1 
                AND RM.VendorID =  CASE WHEN ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR, @VendorID) + ' = ''-1'' THEN RM.VendorID
                                     ELSE '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, @VendorID) +' END
                AND (RM.ReceiverDate BETWEEN ' + CHAR(39) +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), @FromDate, 126) + CHAR(39) +'  AND  ' + CHAR(39) +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), @ToDate, 126) + CHAR(39) +')
                ORDER BY RM.ReceiverDate '
```

My question is: how to add `DISTINCT` to the `ReceiverId` ?

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DISTINCT'.

in the C# code behind

Comment: `DISTINCT` doesn't work on an attribute, it works on the whole result set. `DISTINCT` only removes those records from the result which are identical **in all attributes**. You'll have to decide how you define which records are distinct from one-another

Comment: What happens if you put `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` and before `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: Getting repeated records

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: So, if you don't want to apply `DISTINCT` to the other columns, and there may be *multiple* rows for any given unique `ReceiverId`, how are *we* (and SQL Server) meant to know *which* row's values should be used to supply data in the other columns? Give us what *rule* you want to apply for the other columns.

Comment: Thank you @AndreasNiedermair

Comment: ok ill show my code now @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: i added my full code @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @user2115618 - I've not been asking for more code. What I've said is that, say, you'll have two rows for `ReceiverId` 4. In one of those rows, the value in `VendorName` is `abc`. In the other row, it's `def`. What *rule* do we follow to work out what value is to appear in the results, now that there's only *one* row for `ReceiverId` 4? (Same question for other columns). Once you can answer **that**, we might have a chance of answering the question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever   now i want to only Receiver 4 where VendorName can be either abc or def

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte 
as
(
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReceiverId   ORDER BY ReceiverId  ) AS dupCount, *
from(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ReceivedDate) AS [S. No.]
                  ,RM.ReceiverId  
                  ,RM.ReceiverName'
                  ,VM.VendorName
                  , XYZ columns .....
                 From Receiver RM
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN VendorMaster VM on VM.VendorID = RM.VendorId 
) tab
)
select S. No.
                  ,ReceiverId  
                  ,ReceiverName
                  ,VendorName
                  , XYZ columns 
from cte 
where dupcount=1;
```

try using cte.

Comment: Can you explain me how this is happening

Comment: I am using Row_Number()  function over your result set query. Every row is assigned a number which is stored in column "dupcount". This number is based on the value of ReceiverId column in that row. This number indicates the number of times a particular value of ReceiverId has been encountered by select query. For e.g. if in the table value '2' for receiverid occurs twice in two different rows, then first row has dupcount value '1' and second row has 'dupcount' value '2'. All the rows that have 'dupcount' value greater than 1 are considered duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ReadData NVARCHAR(MAX);
    set @ReadData = 'SELECT * 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ReceivedDate) AS [S. No.] 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ReceiverId,
                     ReceivedDate
                     ,ReceiverName
                     , XYZ columns .....
                     From Receiver .........
                     INNER JOIN .......)'
```

You can't use the row_number and distinct on same level.

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: `DISTINCT` can't be used for a specific column rather should be used for all column in select list.